# creating list of directories or filepaths

Tags: python, list

I am in the very early stages of my python education.

I am trying to create a list of directories taken from user input.

I am not sure what the syntax is for listing directories

here is what i have so far:

```
import os
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox



master = Tk()
master.geometry("600x100+700+400")#remember its .geometry("WidthxHeight(+or-)X(+or-)Y")


filePath = Label(text="Enter filepath of files to convert")

filePath.pack()

e = Entry(master,width=60)

e.pack()

e.focus_set()

def convert():

    myDirectory = e.get()
    filepaths= '['+e.get()+']'

    for i in filepaths:
        filesToChange=os.listdir(i)
            for f in filesToChange:
            cmd = '/Applications/OpenImageIO/dist/macosx/bin/iconvert --inplace --scanline --compression zip -d half ' + os.path.join(i,f)
            os.system(cmd)

def happyComp():



    window = Tk()
    window.wm_withdraw()

    window.geometry("1x1+200+200")#remember its .geometry("WidthxHeight(+or-)X(+or-)Y")
    tkMessageBox.showerror(title="Happy Compositing!",message="Converted!",parent=window)


def click():

    convert()
    happyComp()


b = Button(master, text="convert now!!!", width=10, command=click)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

the user would enter in the text field multiple directories separated by a comma. SO far it looks like python sees each letter in the file path as a individual part of the list... is there anyway to make it see each file path as a filepath?

Comment: * I only see variable `filePath` defined, where does `filepaths` come from?  

* What does the `e.pack` line do? Does it transform the variable?  

* How is `convert` called?

Comment: oops, i did't copy everything, here is the whole script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, if you pass a string to a for loop (e.g. for i in "hello":), it will return each letter separately.  I think what you want is `for i in filepaths.split(",")` which will take the string and split it up by commas.  You will probably also want to:

1. call strip (e.g. `filepath = i.strip()`) within your loop (in case the user put dir1, dir2, dir3 instead of dir1,dir2,dir3)
2. check that what you got back was a file (and probably that it was an image or whatever); I believe os.listdir will return . and .. on unixy systems; a simple check if you know you have all .jpg's is `if f.endswith(".jpg")`)

Edit: removed point 3 as noticed that you did use os.path.join offscreen

Comment: Thank you so much,that worked great! I will start looking into your other suggestions to improve my code.

Comment: would i put:   for i in directories.split(","):
               i.strip('')
               filesToChange=os.listdir(i)